# Is it possible to get Netflix working with HTML5

Tags: netflix, html5

I just read how Chromebooks and Windows 8 are now supporting HTML5 playback on Netflix instead of Silverlight. The site is still requiring users to install silverlight (when you login from Linux computers) Is it possible to emulate Windows 8 or Chromebook?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Muktware](http://www.muktware.com/2013/10/netflix-adds-html5-playback-support-coming-linux/15182), Netflix Adds HTML5 Playback, Support Coming For Linux.  So not as of yet, but it will be available in the near future.  For that time being you can use some workarounds that include running the entire browser in Wine, or running a Silverlight plugin in Wine and make it compatible with the browser.

Comment: Little note to Wine, I would install PlayOnLinux. This allows each program to have their own Wine Config, etc. It will save a lot of pain in the long run...

Comment: "it will be available in the near future"... where do you see that? All I see is confirmation that Netflix is testing Linux to see if it will be a possibility. No assured "Coming For Linux" or "near future." Still good news, though... :)

Comment: @michaelms it works now on chrome with a little bit of tricking, http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/netflix-linux-html5-support-plugins